# singularity gs remove the left/right margins

Tags: singularitygs

I am using the singularitygs for the first time. I was wondering how to remove the left/right margins (gutters)? Like the alpha/omega options in the 960gs. Is there anything like that?

Thank you. I am aware of the $location.
I did not describe my problem properly

so the following scenario:

```
<article>
    <div class="teaser"></div>
    <div class="teaser"></div>
    <div class="teaser"></div>
    <div class="teaser"></div>
</article>
<sidebar></sidebar>

$grids: 12;
$gutters: .2;

article {
    @include grid-span(8);
}
sidebar {
    @include grid-span(4, 9);
}
.teaser { 
    @include float-span(4, 1, 8);
    &:nth-child(odd) {
        // here i want to remove the right-margin - because otherwise the containers are not floating. dirty way would be: margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Singularity has a location variable as the second argument. `@include grid-span($width, $location);`You can change $location to 1 if it is the first column on your grid or 12 if it is the last column on your 12 column grid.

By default Singularity uses the [isolation method](http://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret) of writing grids so this location value is important for moving things around on your grid. You can switch to more traditional floats by writing `$output: float;`

Comment: Additionally, if you're use to the float output method (like what 960 uses) and are using a symmetric grid (a number of equal sized columns), you can use [float-span](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#float-span), which will allow you to only pass in the number of columns you'd like to span, plus first/last for first in row/last in row

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an option to set the gutters which is `add-gutter(x);`.

For example:

```
.sidebar {
  @include add-gutter(0);
  @include grid-span(2, 1);
}

.main {
  @include add-gutter(0);
  @include grid-span(10, 3);
}
```

From the docs: https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/wiki/Creating-Grids#gutter-styles.